# Include posts edited by the Community user in searches with wiki:yes/true/1

Tags: feature-request, search, community-user

I found a way to search for all community wiki posts using `wiki:1` (pic one) but this search does not include posts edited by the Community user (pic two).

***Pic One***

[image]

***Pic Two***

[image]

This could also be an alternate search parameter, for example, `community:1/yes/true`

Comment: The second pic is not of a community wiki. It's just a post that's been edited by the community user (this happens for different reasons - one is if a non-member suggests an edit).

Comment: @Kodos Johnson i am try to search _community_ edited post

Comment: I made quite a few changes with my recent edit. If they conflict with your intent, please do roll them back. I took a greater liberty editing it than I normally would.

Comment: ah it's a feature request, I misunderstood.

Comment: This is essentially asking for a search operator to be able to find posts that have been edited by a specified user (in this case -1, Community). I doubt that is something we could ever implement because there is not a list of people who have edited a post available in the Posts table - it'd require looking in PostHistory which gets far too complicated. You're better off writing a query in [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think it would be better if you used SEDE.

Answer (score 7):

Those are two totally different things, the request makes little sense.

Posts that appear as edited by the Community user mean one of two things:

1. Suggested edit by anonymous visitor that was approved, or
2. The user who edited the post has been deleted.

Neither of those got anything to do with Community Wiki posts.

You can see all edits "made" by Community user [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions), i.e. "Revisions" tab of the Community user's profile page activity.

Comment: there is more than 7000k post .. what about tag ?  this link is not give the feature  like  `[html] wiki:1`

Comment: @noor It would be more beneficial for you to explain what your end result is. What exact information are you trying to fetch and why? As this answer explains, a post being community wiki and a post having been edited by the Community user are not remotely similar concepts. If you provided more details for what exact information you're trying to fetch, someone could write a query for you. Explaining why you want it could also lead to discussion about better ways of getting it. The vague request as it stands now doesn't really benefit anyone, including you.

Comment: @animuson  I try to search community edited post - pic two (from the question)..i believe that valuable post are edited by community ... if i searched  `[html] user: -1` . this parameter also give _community wiki_ post - pic one(from the question)...

Comment: @noor Searching for `user:-1` would search for `user:1` because it does not accept negative values. That search would also only return posts authored by the user (so if `user:-1` really did work, it would return nothing, because Community does not own any posts on the site), not posts edited by the user. If you have a reason to be searching for posts edited by a user, you will have to use SEDE, which is meant for manually creating these odd requests that cannot be built into the site.

Comment: @animuson I am try to search for _community_ post .. so my request was  `[html] community:1` like  `[html] wiki:1`  .. maybe it's complicated .. thanks for response ..

Answer (score 4):

It's been established by others already that you're conflating *Community Wiki* posts with posts *edited by the user* Community♦.

Also, as stated by [@animuson♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson), implementing this in the search bar may be architecturally impractical, since all the current search operators look through data immediately related to posts themselves, and edit/ revision data is stored separately.

That said, if for some reason you still want to filter posts that have been edited by the Community♦ user (or any user for that matter) by a single tag, you can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1350968/search-for-user-edits-of-posts-with-tag) I put together:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1000
  ph.PostId AS [Post Link],
  p.Tags,
  ph.CreationDate AS 'Date'
FROM
  PostHistory ph
  JOIN Posts p ON ph.PostId = p.Id
WHERE 
  ph.UserId = ##UserId:int## AND -- Select Community♦ User
  (ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 4 OR -- Select only post edits
  ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 5 OR
  ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 6) AND
  p.Tags LIKE '%<##TagName##>%'
ORDER BY 
  ph.CreationDate DESC
```