# the evaluation of posts edited by the user Community in SO

Tags: discussion, edits, community-wiki, community-user, community

From this question: [Include posts edited by the Community user in searches with wiki:yes/true/1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358560/include-posts-edited-by-the-community-user-in-searches-with-wikiyes-true-1)

What are the purposes of posts edited by the user Community, rules, value of those type of posts etc.?

Example Picture:

[image]

Comment: A response to your deleted question: I did not downvote your post. However, I think that your question is not clear enough to other users.

Comment: In particular: why a badge? It's not that well explained what the purpose or definition of the badge would be.

Answer (score 8):

The Community user owns [all suggested edits from anonymous users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user).

However, from your screenshot, it appears that the edit was done in 2017. Hence, it is likely part of the [transition from HTTP to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only). At that time, the Community user replaced all links in HTTP with HTTPS. This can be identified from [the Revision History](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/19739/24):

> replaced http://stackoverflow.com/ with https://stackoverflow.com/

Furthermore, the Community user also assisted in editing posts during the [migration to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) this year.

See more information about the Community user at [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user).

Comment: is there any purpose of edit for good posts ? i see many good question/answer edited by community .. or maybe i am wrong ..

Comment: @noor The Community user isn't an actual person; it's a bot so it does not edit posts itself. When anonymous users edit, the edit is simply *credited* to the Community user. The Community also does maintenance work (examples listed in my answer).